# Approximate hashtable, does such a data structure exist?

Tags: java, hashtable

I don't figure out how to implement a special hash table.
The idea would be that the hash table gives an approximate
match. So a perfect hash table (such as found in java.util)
just gives a map, such that:

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
...
x = h.get(y);
```

If x is the result of applying the map h to the argument y,
i.e. basically in mathematics it would be a function 
namely x = h(y). Now for the approximate match, what about a 
data structure that gives me quickly:

```
 x = h(k) where k=max { z<=y | h(z)!=null }
```

The problem is k can be very far away from the given y. For example
y could be 2000, and the next occupied slot k could be 1000. Some
linear search would be costly, the data structure should do the job
more quickly.

I know how to do it with a tree(*), but something with a hash, can this 
also work? Or maybe combine some tree and hash properties in the sought 
of data structure? Some data structure that tends toward O(1) access?

Bye

(*) You can use a tree ordered by y, and find something next below or equal y.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as **Spatial hashing**. Keep in mind it has to be tailored for your specific domain.

It can be used when the *hash* tells you something about logical arrangement of objects. So when `|hash(a)-hash(b)| < |hash(a)-hash(c)|` means `b` is *closer*/*more similar* to `a` than `c` is.

Then the basic idea is that you divide the space into buckets (e.g. drop the least significant digits of the hash -- the naive approach) and your spatial hash is this *bucket ID*. You have to take care of the edge cases, when the objects are very near to each other, while being on the boundary of the buckets (e.g. `h(1999) = 1` but `h(2000)=2`). You can solve this by two overlapping hashes and having two separate hash maps for them and querying both of them, or looking to the neighboring *buckets* etc...

As I sais in the beginning, this has to be thought through very well.

The tree (e.g. KD-tree for higher dimensions) isn't so demanding in the design phase and is generally a more convenient approach to *nearest neighbor(s)* querying.

Answer (score 0):

The specific formula you give suggests you want a set that can retrieve the greatest item less than a given input.

One simple approach to achieving that would be to keep a sorted list of the items, and perform a binary search to locate the position in the list at which the given element would be inserted, then return the element equal to or less than that element.

As always, any set can be converted into a map by using a pair object to wrap the key-value pair, or by maintaining a parallel data structure for the values.

For an array-based approach, the runtime will be O(log n) for retrieval and O(n) for insertion of a single element. If 'add all' sorts the added elements and then merges them, it can be O(n log n).

It's not possible<sup>1</sup> to have a constant-time algorithm that can answer what the first element less than a given element is using a hashing approach; a good hashing algorithm spreads out similar (but non-equal) items, to avoid having many similar items fall into the same bucket and destroy the desired constant-time retrieval behavior, this means the elements of a hash set (or map) are very deliberately not even remotely close to sorted order, they are as close to randomly distributed as we could achieve while using an efficient repeatable hashing algorithm.

---

<sub>1. Of course, proving that it's not possible is difficult, since one can't easily prove that there isn't a simple repeatable constant-time request that will reliably convince an oracle (or God, if God were that easy to manipulate) to give you the answer to the question you want, but it seems unlikely.</sub>

Comment: Requirement is only tends toward O(1), but I guess this is not mathematically precise.